# In ClearCase, is there a way to find out if a file is locked?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

In ClearCase, is there a way to find out if a file is locked without checking out the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `cleartool lslock myFile@@` is enough.
(the `@@` would be to list the locks on the element file. Without the `@@`, that would check only if the *version* of the file is locked)

If the file is visible in your view, that is all you need. See [man lslock](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lslock.htm).

Note: if the file itself is not locked, that doesn't mean there is no lock: its branch can be locked (or its associated Stream in UCM), or the Vob itself can be locked.